# Will a rotating rigid disk precess in microgravity?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, gyroscopes, precession

Given a wheel like a disk with some angular velocity $\omega$, will it precess in microgravity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rotating disk, orbiting the earth in free fall, will precess only to the extent that gravity has an observable gradient within the volume of the disk.